# Creating a docker file for a program with multiple modules

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to create a Dockerfile for a python program, which contains multiple modules and folders as well as CSV files. However, all the examples I have found online for a python Dockerfile seem to assume you just have a single module. i.e. like the following:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

This assumes the below folder structure

```
python-docker
|____ app.py
|____ requirements.txt
|____ Dockerfile
```

So how would I dockerize my app, which has the below folder structure and also takes **command-line arguments**?

```
python-docker
|____ src
      |____ files
           |____ Data
                     |___ data.csv
            |____ ID
                    |___ id.csv
       |___ heplpers
            |___ helper.py
            |___ split_files.py
        - compile_csv.py
        - mysql.py
|___ main.py
|___ README.md    
|____ requirements.txt
|____ Dockerfile
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, let us say if you want to run compile_csv.py, since you have used COPY . . in the Dockerfile you just need to change your workdir so that would be WORKDIR /src then you can run the command CMD ["python3", "compile_csv.py", command-line-arguments]

Comment: @darthbaba The main file which needs to be run is `main.py` All the modules help run the main functionality

Comment: Directly run the main.py from /app CMD  ["python3", "main.py", command-line-arguments]